# Tomcat duplicated logging into catalina.out and in files which configured from log4j

Tags: tomcat, log4j

Using Tomcat 7 and use log4j log4j.properties to log into different files per service;
my log4j.properties looks like this:

```
log4j.debug=TRUE                
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CONSOLE
log4j.category.org.jboss.resteasy=INFO
log4j.category.ge.mycompany.packageone=DEBUG, MT
log4j.category.ge.mycompany.packagetwo.api=DEBUG, MTAPI


log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.SSSS} %p %t %c %m%n

log4j.appender.MT=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MT.File=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/logs/first-file.log
log4j.appender.MT.DatePattern ='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.MT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.SSSS} %p %t %c %m%n

log4j.appender.MTAPI=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MTAPI.File=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/logs/secont-file-api.log
log4j.appender.MTAPI.DatePattern ='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.MTAPI.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MTAPI.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.SSSS} %p %t %c %m%n
```

my main problem is that some logs is logging into files which created from this property and also into catalina.out 
is there any way to avoid this duplicated logging.

Answer (score 0):

Before loading log4j configuration tomcat is setting up *CATALINA_OUT* variable in starting script.
You can try to overwrite this in **setenv.sh** with:

```
CATALINA_OUT="/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/logs/first-file.log"
```